# delete items from 3 different lists

Tags: python, list, pyqt, qlistwidget

I need some help with deleting some items from some lists at the same time, when  a button is clicked.

This is the code:

```
class Window(QMainWindow):
  list_1 = []  #The items are strings
  list_2 = []  #The items are strings

  def __init__(self):
    #A lot of stuff in here

  def fillLists(self):
    #I fill the lists list_1 and list_2 with this method

  def callAnotherClass(self):
    self.AnotherClass().exec_()   #I do this to open a QDialog in a new window

class AnotherClass(QDialog):
  def __init__(self):
    QDialog.__init__(self)

    self.listWidget = QListWidget()

  def fillListWidget(self):
    #I fill self.listWidget in here

  def deleteItems(self):
    item_index = self.listWidget.currentRow()
    item_selected = self.listWidget.currentItem().text()
    for i in Window.list_2:
      if i == item_selected:
        ?????????? #Here is where i get confussed
```

When i open the `QDialog` with a combination of keys, i see in the `QListWidget` some items. In the `deleteItems` method, i get the index and the text from the item that i selected in the `QListWidget`. That works fine.

What i need to do is to delete the item from the `list_1`, `list_2`, and the `QListWidget` when i press a button (that i have already created).

How can i do this? Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python lists have a "remove" object that perform that action directly:

```
Window.list_2.remove(item_selected)
```

(with no need for your for loop)

If you ever need to perform more complex operations on the list items, you can retrieve an item's index with the `index` method instead:

```
position = Window.list_2.index(item_selected)
Window.list_2[position] += "(selected)"
```

And in some ocasions you will want to do a for loop getting to the actual index, as well as the content at that index of a list or other sequence. In that case, use the builtin `enumerate`.

Using the enumerate pattern, (if `remove`did not exist) would look like:

```
for index, content in enumerate(Window.list_2):
  if content == item_selected:
      del Window.list_2[index]
      # must break out of the for loop,
      # as the original list now has changed: 
      break
```

Comment: Thank you, the `enumerate` pattern worked for what i needed Sorry for bothering you, but is there a method to refresh the `QListWidget` or the `QDialog` to see it without the item i have just deleted. I tried the `repaint` method but it does not work.

Comment: I'd suggest you ask another question for that - since it is Qt related, Qt people might coem up to a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

if you have the value, then just find its index in each list and then delete it. Something like:

```
 item_selected = self.listWidget.currentItem().text()
 i = Window.list_2.index(item_selected)
 if i >= 0: 
    del Window.list_2[i]
```

You can also use directly `Widow.list_x.remove(value)` but it can throw an exception if the value does not exist.

Comment: Thank yot for youe answer. It works for list_2 and list_1, but it does not work for the `QlistWidget`. The `QListWidget`is filled with the item of list_2. So, when i delete an item from list_2, why it is not deleted in the listWidget too?