# Getting an index that is not the right one

Tags: python, list, indexing, pyqt

I asked this question a few days ago:

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35131064/delete-items-from-3-different-lists)

And i solved the problem with your help. Now i just added a few more lines in the method, and i am getting an index error that i did not have before.

This is the code with the extra lines that i added:

```
class Window(QMainWindow):
  list_1 = []  #The items are strings
  list_2 = []  #The items are strings

  def __init__(self):
    #A lot of stuff in here

  def fillLists(self):
    #I fill the lists list_1 and list_2 with this method

  def callAnotherClass(self):
    self.AnotherClass().exec_()   #I do this to open a QDialog in a new window

class AnotherClass(QDialog):
  def __init__(self, parent):
    super(QDialog,self).__init__(parent)

    self.listWidget = QListWidget()

  def fillListWidget(self):
    #I fill self.listWidget in here

  def deleteItems(self):
    item_index = self.listWidget.currentRow()
    self.listWidget.takeItem(item_index)
    item_selected = self.listWidget.currentItem().text()
    list_2_item = Window.list_2.index(item_selected)

    for index, content in enumerate(Window.list_2):
        if content == item_selected:
            del Window.list_2[index]
            del Window.list_1[index]

            widget = self.parent().splitter.widget(index)
            widget.hide()

            break
```

SO, when i print the `item_selected` variable, the text is not the one that i selected in the ListWidget. For example, if i have 2 items, i select the item 1, the `item_selected` variable prints "item 2".

I really do not know where is the problem.

Hope you can help me.

Comment: You are using takeItem() method, that acts as a pop()... So when you use currentItem() method just after, it returns you the next item.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I didn`t know that `takeItem` works like a pop(). So, i put the `takeItem` line after the `currentItem` line. Tnak you for your help again.

Answer (score 1):

You are using takeItem() method, that acts as a pop(). It means that when you use currentItem() method just after, it returns you the next item.

Solution for you is to call currentItem() before calling takeItem().

Comment: This is correct. However, `takeItem()` returns the taken item, so really the OP should do `item_selected  = self.listWidget.takeItem(item_index)` followed by `selection = item_selected.text()`.

Comment: Schollii, you are right, it improves the code. @PabloFlores I think however that my answer could be accepted.